# Auto Insert Address on adjacent cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a spreadsheet which enters address automatically on adjacent cell when I type in the company name.

The script will be as I type in company name in cell A1, it will search for matching name in another spreadsheet which I saved the company name and address, then copy the corresponding address back into the adjacent cell A2.

I need this to keep track the job logbook.

Comment: Roger....where art thou...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a vlookup function

=VLOOKUP(E138,Status!A:K,6,false)
E138=the Control or reference number (i.e. name) that will be the same in this sheet and the sheet with your data
Status!A:K=the tab that has your data and the columns that the data is in. the first column should be the one that has the reference numbers (i.e. name)
6=the column that has the data you need (i.e. address)